# Getting Value of Parameter from Outer Stored Procedure - Nested Stored Procedures

Tags: stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure. I want to know if I could get the value of the parameter that came from the outer stored procedure and pass it onto the inner stored procedure. Below is my stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[OuterStoredProcedure] 
@OuterParameter_FirstName VARCHAR(50),
@InnerParameter_Spouse_FirstName VARCHAR(50)
```

AS
BEGIN

```
DECLARE @DT DATETIME
SET @DT = GETDATE()

INSERT EMPLOYEE_DETAILS WITH (ROWLOCK)
(
    FirstName
)

VALUES
(
    @OuterParameter_FirstName
)

DECLARE @STOREPROC_QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @STOREPROC_QUERY = 'CREATE PROCEDURE InnerStoredProcedure
                        AS
                        BEGIN
                            DECLARE @DT DATETIME
                            SET @DT = GETDATE()

                            INSERT EMPLOYEE_SPOUSE WITH(ROWLOCK)
                            (
                                Spouse_FirstName
                            )

                            VALUES
                            (
                                ''HOW WOULD I BE ABLE TO PASS THE VALUE OF THE PARAMETER @InnerParameter_Spouse_FirstName INSIDE THIS SECTION''
                            )
                        END'

EXEC(@STOREPROC_QUERY)
```

END

Comment: Why are you creating a stored procedure using dynamic sql???? Why are you even using dynamic sql here at all?

Comment: This is what the client needed. I'm also not sure about what they're trying to do.

Comment: No idea what you mean by the client needed to use dynamic sql to create a procedure. If you are not sure what the purpose of the code I don't know how you can expect somebody else to offer much assistance.

Comment: They use stored procedures in generating their reports.

Comment: Using stored procs is a great idea. That doesn't explain using dynamic sql to create them. Also, doing inserts like you have here is nothing like anything you should see in a report.

Comment: This is not the actual stored procedure, but the structure of the stored procedure that I am currently working in is very similar to this one. Other than reports, they also use stored procedures in notifications and others. Aside from using dynamic sql, do you have any suggestions on how to create stored procedures?

Comment: Yes, just create the procedure one time and be done with it. There is no reason to continually create a procedure. Create the procedure with a parameter and pass the value in.

Answer (score 0):

''' +@InnerParameter_Spouse_FirstName + '''

The parameter you needed is still in scope by the time you call the SET Command for your second stored procedure. It should still be able to get the value.